# Epson Epos printer language support

Tags: android, printers, epson, pos, epos

I am trying to print Japanese texts using Epson TM M30 epos printer using epson epos2 SDK but failed. The printed texts are wrong.

```
        mPrinter = new Printer(Printer.TM_M30, Printer.MODEL_ANK, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Printing A simple Japanese text

```
        String text = "ダッカ、バングラデシュ";
        mPrinter.addTextLang(Printer.LANG_JA);
        mPrinter.addTextFont(Printer.FONT_B);
        mPrinter.addText(text);
```

How can I achieve the correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are detailed models in TM-m30 depending on the supported languages.
Multi-byte character sets can be printed only on models that support the target character set.
If you want to print Japanese, you need to use Japanese model.
Next, you need to turn on Kanji character mode, which is probably included in addTextLang().

[Support Information for Each Model: Japanese](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_charcode_en/index.php?content_id=119)

> Only Japanese models support the multi-byte Japanese characters.

[FS &](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=175)

> Select Kanji character mode
>
> This command can be used only for the Japanese, Simplified Chinese, and Traditional Chinese models.

[Thermal line Printer](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=genre&pcat=3)

> **[Models of the TM-m30]**
>
> - ANK model : Standard model, Bluetooth model
> - Japanese model : Bluetooth model
> - Simplified Chinese model : Standard model
> - Traditional Chinese model : Standard model